# how to calculate heritability from half-sib design

Tags: r

I'm trying to measure heritability of a trait, flowering time (FT), for a set of data collected from a half-sib design. The data includes FT for each mother plant and 2 half siblings from that mother plant for ~150 different maternal lines (ML). Paternity is unknown.

I've tried:

1. Estimating heritability with a regression of the maternal FT and the mean sibling FT, and doubling the slope. This worked fine, and produced an estimate of 0.14.
2. Running an ANOVA and using the between ML variation to estimate additive genetic variance. Got the idea from slide 25 of [this powerpoint](https://jvanderw.une.edu.au/gene251-351-lec12_Estimh2.pdf) and from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401894/calculate-within-and-between-variances-and-confidence-intervals-in-r) on within and between variance calculation

   `fit = lm(FT ~ ML, her)`

   `anova(fit)`

**her** is the dataset, which, in this case, only includes the half sib FT values (I excluded the mother FT values for this attempt at heritability)

From the ANOVA output I have have used the "ML" term mean square as the between ML variation, which is also equal to 1/4 of the additive genetic variance because coefficient of relatedness between half-sibs is 0.25. This value turned out to be 0.098. Also, by multiplying this by 4 I could get the additive genetic variance. 
I have used the "residuals" mean square as all variability save for that accounted for by the "ML" term. So, all of variance minus 1/4 of additive genetic variance. This turned out to be 1.342.

And then attempted to calculate heritabilty as `Va/Vp = (4*0.098)/(1.342 + 0.098) = 0.39`

This is quite different from my slope estimate, and I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct.

I've tried things with the sommer and heritability packages of R but haven't had success using either for a half-sib design and haven't found an example of a half-sib design with either package.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" isn't a very specific programming question. Do you need help with programming or statistics? This seems mostly like a statistical question so you might want to ask at [stats.se] instead because statistical questions are on-topic over there.

Comment: Hi steve, very hard to follow what you did in words, without any code..Like @MrFlick mentioned, you might get more help at Cross Validated, or bioinformatics exchange, I can vote to migrate your question there.

Comment: If for both estimates, you are using different datasets, where do you start the comparison? I think it's more important to get one correction first, then think about whether it makes sense biologically, like whether it is so inheritable?

Comment: Thanks for the help, yeah I will try Cross Validated. I couldn't provide a specific coding question, but basically I could not figure out how to calculate heritability with the sommer package, and couldn't find any resources that explained the reasoning behind example code for the package. I'll try Cross Validated to ask about general heritability calculation and go from there